# Why can I not see a field which depends on two other fields related by the OR operator?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, configuration

I'm using the [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module and I have a *field* that I can set while editing my custom content type.

That field is dependent to two other fields which are related by the operator **OR**.

The edition works well, but the field is not visible when I **view** the node.

Can you help?